# Dimension of $\text{Hom}_\bar{\mathbb{C}}(V,W)$ as a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

Let $V,W$ be two complex vector spaces. Then we define $\text{Hom}_\bar{\mathbb{C}}(V,W)=\{f:V \longrightarrow W | f \text{ is antilinear}\}$, where antilinear means that:

- $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
- $f(\lambda x)=\bar{\lambda}f(x)$

For every $x,y \in V, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. I want to calculate the dimension of this space (that it seems to be $\dim V \cdot \dim W$ as in the linear case).

I tried to generalise the one dimensional case where $V=W=\mathbb{C}$. In this setting is easy to see that $\text{Hom}_\bar{\mathbb{C}}(V,W)$ is generated by the complex conjugate $a+bi \longmapsto a-bi$ (because $f(a+bi)=f(a)-if(b)=af(1)-if(1)=f(1)(a-ib)$). I was trying to do the same thing for two generic $V,W$ using the same property, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define new linear space $(W', +, *)$ where multiplication defined as $\lambda*w = \overline{\lambda}w,$ $w \in W'.$ As a set $W'=W.$ It is easy to check that $W$ and $W'$ has the same dimensions. You should consider a basis in $W$ and show that it is also a basis in $W'.$  Now all antilinear functions are linear functions from $V \to W'.$ Thus we get natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}_{\overline{\mathbb{C}}}(V,W) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V,W').$ So they has equal dimensions.